# Get Information of nodes in context with PHP XML Reader

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xmlreader

@those who marked this question as duplicate, please leave a comment why you think this is. Here, we want to get all elements in a certain node. In the other Question they want to get the parent node. This is almost the opposite. Here we are not selecting the people node and its children but rather get ever person within a context. I see it might look similar.

Question:
To be clear: I want to do this with XML Reader.

I have got an XML-file and want to retrieve the content of the name-node within the context people. The name-node also appears in cars, that's why I need the context.

How can I do this?

```
<file>
  <people>
     <person>
        <name>father</name>
        <age>50</age>
     </person>
  </people>
  <car>
     <person>
        <name>mom</name>
        <age>45</age>
     </person>
     <name>Octavia</name>
     <brand>Scoda</brand>
  </car>
  <people>
     <person>
        <name>son</name>
        <age>25</age>
     </person>
     <person>
        <name>daughter</name>
        <age>20</age>
     </person>
  </people>
```

Here is the PHP I got so far:

```
$xmlReader = new XMLReader;

if (!$xmlReader->open($this->_file, null, 1<<19)) {
   die("Failed to open file");
}


while($xmlReader->read()) {
    // set the context
    if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == 'people') {
          // do something with the name of every person
          if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == 'person') {
              $xmlReader->name->readString();
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code:

```
$xmlReader = new XMLReader;

if (!$xmlReader->open($fileURL, null, 1<<19)) {
   die("Failed to open file");
}
while($xmlReader->read()) {
    if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == 'people') {
// We are at the beginning of the node people. 
        while ($xmlReader->read()) {
            if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == 'person') {
// We are at the beginning of the node person. 
                while ($xmlReader->read()) {
                    if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == 'name' && $xmlReader->read())
// And now node 'name. Then we make one read more to step to 'TEXT' type of node. Because 'ELEMENT' does not have value         
                        echo $xmlReader->value.'<br>';
                    else if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == "person")
// This is closing element of node 'persons. Interrupt loop 
                        break;
                }
            }
            if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == "people")
// This is closing element of node 'people. Interrupt loop 
                        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
futher
son
daughter
```

**UPDATE:**
Or put node 'person' to simplexml object. Then loop wiil look like:

```
while($xmlReader->read()) {
    if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == 'person') {           
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlReader->readOuterXML());
        foreach ($xml->name as $name)
            echo $name.'<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Simple XML runs out of memory. My file is very large.

Comment: @hogan I did it. it is work

Comment: Hi splash58, that is a very good first step. Now what happens is that I want to make sure that the node 'person' will just be in 'people' and not in cars. So I somehow must put 'people' in this. I take your example, adapt it and put it up in my question. Do you have an answer for this??

Comment: @hogan just add one more wrapping `while` as now for `<person>` but for `<people>`

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. When I try with my example above (mom is sitting in the the car), then I always get her as well. That I need to exclude. Just the persons in the people tag. I tried a wrapper and add a while-read() but can't get it working right.

Comment: That one was missing: This is closing element of node 'people. Interrupt loop. Sweet, it works. Thank you splash58.